# Eclipse PropertySheetPage - Can it support a multi line property?

Tags: java, eclipse, view, properties, line

I want to use the Eclipse **AdvancedPropertySection** which uses **PropertySheetPage** to **display and edit properties**, but some of my properties
are multi line (e.g. Description).

Problem:
**I can't get the PropertySheetPage to display multi line properties. 
It displays them as a single line, like this:**

[image]

I tried using WrapTextPropertyDescriptor instead of TextPropertyDescriptor, but it doesn't seem to help.

**Is there a way to display multi line properties using the AdvancedPropertySection(PropertySheetPage)?**

Comment: copy your code for class that extends AdvancedPropertySection here...

Answer (score 1):

That's simple if you follow this tutorial: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Properties-View/properties-view.html

You can creating your own custom property descriptor.

I've solved the problem like this:

```
import org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.common.dialogs.TextDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DialogCellEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;

public class TextDialogCellEditor extends DialogCellEditor{

     protected TextDialogCellEditor(Composite parent) {
         super(parent);
      }

    @Override
    protected Object openDialogBox(Control cellEditorWindow) {
        TextDialog textDialog = new TextDialog(cellEditorWindow.getShell(),(String)getValue());
        textDialog.open();
        if(textDialog.getReturnCode()==textDialog.OK){
            setValue(textDialog.getText());
        }
        return getValue();
    }

}
```

This is your own descriptor:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CellEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.PropertyDescriptor;

public class TextDataPropertyDescriptor extends PropertyDescriptor{

    public TextDataPropertyDescriptor(Object id, String displayName) {
        super(id, displayName);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public CellEditor createPropertyEditor(Composite parent) {
        CellEditor editor = new TextDialogCellEditor(parent);
        if (getValidator() != null)
           editor.setValidator(getValidator());
        return editor;

    }


}
```

Use:

```
properties.add(new TextDataPropertyDescriptor(YourClass.PROPERTY_CONTENT,"Content"));
```

Using `import org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.common.dialogs.TextDialog;`, you can update your eclipse with the plugin, http://directory.apache.org/studio/downloads.html,
and update only the package, `org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.common;`.